# How can I report Social Security and Medicare taxes, if my W2 form doesn't have them?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Last year I was a resident alien for tax purpose due to the presence test, and I worked for two employers, and received W-2 from employer A and 1099MISC from employer B.
Both  show zero for Social Security and Medicare taxes, maybe because I was holding F1 visa which confused my employers' HR.

For 1099MISC from employer B, I filled out Schedule C, which further asked me to filled out Schedule SE "Self-Employment Tax" to figure out the part of my Social Security and Medicare taxes from the employment.

For W-2 from employer A, shall I pay social security and medicare taxes, and how? 1040 doesn't seem to calculate them for me, does it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the W-2 doesn't show FICA amounts being taken out, that's on the employer. You need to fill out your tax return with the information shown on your W-2 as is. You should work with employer A to figure out how to pay back that amount.

https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2967041-do-i-have-to-pay-back-fica-and-medicare-taxes-not-withheld-by-my-employer

> **Collecting underwithheld taxes from employees.**
>
> If you withheld no income, social security, or Medicare taxes or less
>   than the correct amount from an employee's wages, you can make it up
>   from later pay to that employee. But you are the one who owes the
>   underpayment. Reimbursement is a matter for settlement between you and
>   the employee. Under withheld income tax and Additional Medicare Tax
>   must be recovered from the employee on or before the last day of the
>   calendar year.
>
> **According to the IRS Tax Code:**
>
> “The employer is liable for the employee tax with respect to all wages
>   paid by him to each of his employees whether or not it is collected
>   from the employee. If, for example, the employer deducts less than the
>   correct amount of tax, or if he fails to deduct any part of the tax,
>   he is nevertheless liable for the correct amount of the tax. Until
>   collected from him the employee also is liable for the employee tax
>   with respect to all the wages received by him.”

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Does it make difference that Employer A and employer B are both my previous employers instead of current one?

Comment: I don't believe so. You may also want to review your W4 to ensure that it is also correct.

Comment: Thanks. For 1099 from employer B, does the "Self-employment tax." in Section A Short Schedule SE in Schedule SE include social security and medicare taxes? i said so in my post, because I guessed so. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The IRS says you are liable.
[Employees’ Responsibility](https://www.irs.gov/uac/employer-and-employee-responsibilities-employment-tax-enforcement):

> Employees who do not have taxes withheld nor remit them personally,
>   are still liable for these taxes and may not qualify for Social
>   Security, Medicare, or unemployment benefits.

The method by which you pay is less clear, as the employer has responsibility to  pay this on your behalf. So, per their directions, you'll need to put a call in to the IRS:  1-800-829-1040

As for filing now, use what the W-2 indicates, and your 1099 income sounds like it's being handled properly via Schedules C and SE.

Comment: Thanks. For 1099 from employer B, does the "Self-employment tax." in Section A Short Schedule SE in Schedule SE include social security and medicare taxes? i said so in my post, because I guessed so. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Self-employment tax is both Social Security and Medicare combined into one fun obligation.